# How to compute the forward facing direction from three angles and then translate along it?

Tags: camera, rotation

Given:

```
float yaw, pitch, roll;
```

How does one compute the forward direction:

```
vec3 forward = computeForwardFromEulers(yaw, pitch, roll);
```

Next, I would like to use this information to translate an object along this axis / heading / forwardDirection.

```
// move 1 unit forward 
forward.?? = 1.0f?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568568/how-to-convert-euler-angles-to-directional-vector

This should answer the first part of your question. A simple google search gave me this result.

For translating, you want to multiply the *direction* you want to move by the *length* you want to move. So, if you want to move forward by 5.0 units, you would write:

```
position = position + forward * 5.0
```

This will move you towards forward by 5.0 units. You can do this with any directional vector:

```
position = position + GlobalUpVector * 2.0
```