# Get direction vector of camera in voxel game

Tags: mathematics, camera, voxels, trigonometry, euler-angles

I am currently working on a Minecraft clone (a voxel game). The feature I'm working on is the ability to break blocks. I have a ray-casting/ray tracing algorithm for traversing the voxels, but the only thing I don't know how to do is find the direction vector of the ray.

How can I find a unit vector representing the direction of a ray in 3D space given the pitch and yaw degrees of the ray (and the ray origin, of course)?

Comment: Did you try searching to find existing Q&A like [How to convert Euler angles to directional vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1568568/3064164) / [How to compute the forward facing direction from three angles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/93188/39518) /  [Spherical to cartesian coordinates](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44738/39518) / [How do I translate a spherical coordinate to a Cartesian one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/81713/39518) / etc? Did you run into any difficulty applying these already published answers to your case?

Comment: The origin is the position of the camera. The direction is the direction that the camera is looking (that may allow you some shortcut to get it, depending on your code). As DMGregory points out, you should be able to find how get that direction from the angles you have.